# Existence of right adjoint functor

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a right adjoint to the forgetful functor from associative commutative rings with 1 to just associative commutative rings?

Comment: If there were, then the forgetful functor you describe would be a left adjoint and hence would send the initial object of one category to the initial object of the other (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629181/adjoint-functor-with-initial-objects for a direct proof). This is not the case (assuming that for the category of rings with 1 you are using unital HMs as the morphisms).

Comment: In my case I think I should use final objects and take a zero-ring.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "in my case" - did I misunderstand your original question? The category of rings with 1 and unital HMs does not have a terminal object.